# How to group a pandas DataFrame by month? Trying its output to have a index with actual last days

Tags: python, pandas, group

I have the following DataFrame, and like to group by month.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = pd.date_range(start='2001-01-01', end='2002-01-01', periods = 80)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(160).reshape(80,2), index=idx.normalize(), columns=['a','b'])
```

With the following codes, I can group `df` by month, but its index label is last days of each ***calendar*** month, but not the last days of each month in `df`.

```
k = df.resample('M').apply(lambda x: x[-1])

k1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).last()
```

For example, `df.loc['2001-01'].index[-1]` is `Timestamp('2001-01-28 00:00:00')`, but not `Timestamp('2001-01-31 00:00:00')`. However, `k` and `k1` includes `2001-01-31` as below.

```
                   a         b
2001-01-31  0.521604  0.716046
2001-02-28  0.584479  0.560608
2001-03-31  0.201605  0.860491
2001-04-30  0.077426  0.711042
2001-05-31  0.544708  0.865880
2001-06-30  0.755516  0.863443
2001-07-31  0.266727  0.107859
2001-08-31  0.683754  0.098337
2001-09-30  0.586217  0.697163
2001-10-31  0.742394  0.160754
2001-11-30  0.655662  0.400128
2001-12-31  0.902192  0.580582
2002-01-31  0.878815  0.555669
```

In other words, I like to group `df` by month and the grouped `df` to have index labels of the last days of each month in `df`, but not the last dates of each ***calendar*** month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@BENY's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71207599/5763165) answer is great for this question. However, if you need to do something more with the group (e.g., calculate some aggregated statistics) then here is another idea that uses the `groupby` method:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.groupby([(df["index"].dt.year),(df["index"].dt.month)]).last().set_index("index")
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try with `duplicated` after trim the index

```
df = df.sort_index()
out = df[~df.index.strftime('%Y-%m').duplicated(keep='last')]
Out[242]: 
                   a         b
2001-01-28  0.984408  0.923390
2001-02-25  0.108587  0.797240
2001-03-29  0.058016  0.025948
2001-04-26  0.095034  0.226460
2001-05-28  0.386954  0.419999
2001-06-30  0.535202  0.576777
2001-07-27  0.389711  0.706282
2001-08-29  0.270434  0.342087
2001-09-30  0.190336  0.872519
2001-10-28  0.333673  0.832585
2001-11-29  0.651579  0.751776
2001-12-27  0.649476  0.748410
2002-01-01  0.670143  0.389339
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my question using @nick's great answer:

```
df['Date'] = df.index
df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).last().set_index('Date')
```